# At what rep level can I get a faction quest in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

After declaring allegiance to a faction, there are quests for legendary items. What reputation level is required to unlock these quests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/152308478/0/0) post on the bungie forums. You need to be level 25, and you must have the faction shader/emblem/class item equipped.

Comment: Thanks. I've never had a shader drop. I'll just keep grinding

Comment: @Balrog good luck, hopefully TTK will increase the drop rate/availability!